# How to create new column to calculate cumulative amount of selected items in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have below this table.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvzH0.png]

and unpivoted become like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uksbp.png]

How can I create a new column to calculate/replace the Monthly Cost become Cost to Date (cumulative as per timeline) and the other Cost Type will still remain as the value it is.

Desired result like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xWd4.png]

Comment: Can't really give you an actual piece of code to do this for you, but you can accomplish this in Power Query M. Insert a step and filter /  sum.